# How to add folder to yii project (yii folder exception)

Tags: yii

I have a Yii project running on website.com and need to add a static folder with static HTML files in it so it will look like this:

- website.com/faq/index.html
- website.com/faq/howto.html

Right now, when I just create a folder and index.html file, it shows the standard yii page that page does not exist.

Is there an exception to ignoring a specific folder as a Yii project?

Any hint and help are appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First add folder like fag inside views folder,then create controller to route webs